# When investigating Monte Carlo convergence, should I reuse previous data?

Tags: sampling, monte-carlo, convergence

I am doing Monte Carlo simulations and I want to investigate the convergence. Two versions come to my mind:

#### 1) Doing every trial independently:

For each trial, I generate new data independent from any previous data. Each trial however, we use more simulations, hence decreasing the confidence interval.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
```

```py
N = 50
sims = np.logspace(1, 3, N).astype(int)
means = np.zeros(N)
sstds = np.zeros(N)

for i, sim in enumerate(sims):
    x = np.random.geometric(0.01, size=sim)

    means[i] = np.mean(x)
    sstds[i] = np.std(x, ddof=1)

cis = 1.96 * sstds / np.sqrt(sims)

plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.plot(sims, means)
plt.fill_between(sims, means+cis, means-cis, alpha=0.4)
plt.xscale("log")

plt.hlines(y=100, xmin=sims[0], xmax=sims[-1], color="red")
```

Now the output is a bit more spiky.

[image]

#### 2) Reusing the previous trial in the next trial

Instead of doing a new indepndent simulation, I no progressively add simulations, so the mean of this single simulation I do is converging.

```py
N = 50
sims = np.logspace(1, 3, N).astype(int)
means = np.zeros(N)
sstds = np.zeros(N)

x = np.random.geometric(0.01, size=10**3)

for i, sim in enumerate(sims):

    means[i] = np.mean(x[:sim])
    sstds[i] = np.std(x[:sim], ddof=1)

cis = 1.96 * sstds / np.sqrt(sims)

plt.figure(figsize=(15,5))
plt.plot(sims, means)
plt.fill_between(sims, means+cis, means-cis, alpha=0.4)
plt.xscale("log")

plt.hlines(y=100, xmin=sims[0], xmax=sims[-1], color="red")
```

Now the plot looks different, like it looks more correct but I am not sure if it is actually better

[image]

#### Question

Is any of these two methods better? Or is it just a matter of preference? Which one should I use?

#### Update

I accepted an answer now that gave sound reasoning on why to chose the second one. However if anyone reading this feels like there are other arguments in favor of any of the two visualisation / convergence methods, I would be very happy to hear them as answer/comment!

Comment: Is this the difference between running 50 independent simulations (of sizes 10 to 10000) vs. one simulation done in 50 steps (from 10 to 10000)?

Comment: Yes, that is what I am doing. Which of these 2 approaches is better for showing convergence?

Comment: What do you want to show is converging and where is it converging to? From your question, it *seems* like you want to compare convergence of the sample mean with a sample size of 10^1, 10^1 + 1, .... 10^3.

Comment: Actually this is part of my question. My main intent is to visualise how MC converges to the analytical solution. However in general I find that MC convergence (i.e. that doing more simulations means the confidence interval shrinks) is often visualised similarly, and I am interested in which of the 2 methods above are more commonly used or if there is any more/less correct than the other

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second method. It shows the incremental improvement as you increase the sample size during a single simulation.

Take your routines above, delete the confidence interval shading, and put them in a loop, looping 10 times to get 10 lines. You should see the second one looks like those law of large number graphs you see, such as this one:

https://alphaarchitect.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/lawoflargenumbers.png

Whereas the first method won’t look like that.